# Update title/subtitle for custom annotation on an MKMapView

Tags: iphone, ios4, mkmapview

I created a custom annotation to display my data. The data comes from moving vehicles and I've got to update their location on the map as well as their title (it shows the last update time).

My first approach was to simply remove all annotations and recreate them. However this leads to a lot of horrible flickering (the map clears, and then all annotations appear again) and the map blocks while it redraws. Less than optimal solution.

In the OS4 SDK they improved the `MKMapViewAnnotation` and I can now set the coordinates (they were readonly before). Changing the coordinates moves the view nicely where it should be  without any flickering. That solved one of my issues.

It said in the API documentation that changing the title of the `MKAnnotation` will update the `MKAnnotationView`. Indeed that's the case for the `MKPinView`. If I update the `MKAnnotation`'s coordinates and title, the pin moves and shows the new data.

How can I achieve the same result using my custom `MKAnnotationView`? I can't see any way to ask the view to refresh.
I tried calling `setNeedsLayout` on the `MKAnnotationView` but that only resulted in the view disappearing.

Cheers.

Comment: did you find a solution to this at all?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't. I had to destroy and re-create the annotation. The suggested setNeedsDisplay or other redraw clues didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

`MKMapView` uses [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) to observe changes to the `title` and `subtitle` properties. The easiest way to ensure the map view notices your changes, is to make them properties and use the `setTitle:` / `setSubtitle:` methods (or `self.title = @"...";` — note that the `self.` notation is required):

#### `CustomAnnotation.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

- (void)changeAnnotation;
```

#### `CustomAnnotation.m`

```
@synthesize title, subtitle;

- (void)changeAnnotation {
    self.title = @"New title!";
    [self setSubtitle:@"New subtitle!"];
}
```

The synthesized property setters handle the rigors of key-value observing for you. Otherwise, you'll have to call [`willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) yourself; these are implemented in `NSObject`:

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"title"];
[title release];
title = @"New title.";
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"title"];
```

Comment: You don't need to use willChangeValueForKey/didChangeValueForKey: if you implement setTitle/setSubtitle yourself. (KVO magic mappens automatically if you use the standard setter names.)

Answer (score 0):

Tried `setNeedsDisplay`?