# How implement the subtitle's update in mkannotationview after the tap on the corresponding annnotationview

Tags: ios, mkannotation, mkannotationview, subtitle

Just like the googlemap's implementation.
After a tap on the annotation view ,callout bubble will show ,and then acquire the network to get some information .After we got it ,we need to update the annotationview's subtitle.
How to implement this effect.Thanks much!

Comment: can you elaborate  your question? What u want exactly

Comment: thanks,I've resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For the KVO has been implement by the annotation view ,you just need to implement
the two functions by yourself:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
```

then when you need to change the title or subtitle on the annotation view

```
self.title = @"New title!";
[self setSubtitle:@"New subtitle!"];
```

then the update on the corresponding annotation view will show up.

click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316552/update-title-subtitle-for-custom-annotation-on-an-mkmapview),that's the answer,my appreciation to this.